# Why belongsTo child model got from parent model isn't of DS.Model type

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to access a related(belongsTo) model from the parent model. 
In a component I am receiving this top level employee model and there I am trying to access address model as below.

this.get('employee').get('address')

but the address object I received is not of Model type, so I am not able to call any Model function on it. Surprisingly `this.get('employee')` returns a model object and i am able to call any Model function using it.

Complete Employee model is as below

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  serialNo: DS.attr('string'), 
  name: DS.attr('string'), 
  address: DS.belongsTo('employee/address')
});
```

and the address model is

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  addressId: DS.attr('string'),
  streetNo: DS.attr('string'),
  city: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you share complete file of both models Employee and Address models.

```
employee= DS.Model.extend({
 serialNo: DS.attr('number'), 
 name: DS.attr('number'), 
 address:  DS.belongsTo('address', { inverse: 'employee' }) ,
 });
```

Address model should be something like that

```
 address= DS.Model.extend({
     employee:  DS.belongsTo('employee', { inverse: 'address' }) ,
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But adding inrverse doesn't make any difference. address model got from  this.get('employee').get('address') still is not of DS.Model type

Comment: are you sure that employee have associated address in Ember inspector?
it will be helpful if you share ember inspector snapshots related to employee and address models.

Comment: For the sake of confidentiality i can not put original ember inspector snapshot here. I have changed names also. But i took a look at the employee object in Ember Inspector data in Belongs To tab i can see a promise object against 'address'. Does this help ?

Comment: if ember inspector is showing address object against employee belongs to relation than its mean address is correctly associated and created against employee. 
if you are not able to share more info than we are not able to resolve such issues.

Comment: thanks for the reply. My issues is not that i am not able to get address object from employee. this.get('employee').get('address') returns an object which has all the address properties, but is not of DS.Model type so i am able to use any Model function on address object

Comment: How you are checking to verify either it is Model Type or not? share some more related code of controller and route file where you find address or employee model.

Comment: by using instanceof operator. Also if I call any model function e.g. serialize, toJSON on this.get('employee').get('address') object on browser console i can see error -                                                                 VM8742:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.get(...).get(...).toJSON is not a function(…)